# How to declare global variable for linq query that produces a sequence of anonymous types

Tags: c#, linq, variables, anonymous-types, declare

I have a linq query that produces a sequence of anonymous types. The query is defined as:

```
var query = from a in Db.Table1
    join b from Db.Table2
    join...
    ...
    select new {
     a.field1, a.field2, 
     b.field1, NewName = b.field2 };
```

Now I would like to use this query in the following scenario:

```
if (x == 1)
{ query = ...
  ...rest of code_1 }
if (x == 2)
{ query = ...
  ...rest of code_2 }
```

'Query' from first 'if' will use different tables, joins and where statement than query from second 'if', however both will have exactly the same 'select new' statement.

In order to do that I need to declare a variable 'query' that will be visible inside 'if' statements.

When I checked 'type' of 'query' by using:

```
query.GetType().ToString();
```

it gives me:

```
query type = 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType7`14[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Decimal,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.Decimal,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]'
```

I can't declare a separate class as I can only write inside a method that I am writing code of.
How should I declare a 'query' variable?

Comment: You can either use the non-generic `IQeuryable`or `dynamic`.

Comment: Seems like a lot of trouble just to create problems for yourself.

Comment: With IQueryable I won't be able to use later on i.e.  if (query.Count() > 0) - am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to define it using **example** like this:

```
var query = Enumerable.Repeat(new
{
    field1 = default(int),
    field2 = default(string),
    field3 = default(string),
    // other fields ...        
}, 0).AsQueryable();
```

where `field1`, `field2` etc. should be your concrete property names with their actual types, in the exact order used inside the inner selects.

Comment: field1, field2 etc. are just 'some' fields. I didn't mean name/property of a.field1 is same as for b.field1. But I get your point... and I am aware of it.

Comment: Yep, sorry, this is what I was thinking. But I needed a concrete names/types for making a matching example. Anyway, I think you've got the point, I'll delete that part from the answer.

Comment: I forget to mention that your solution is working for me perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

As a continuation to this solution I would like to ask for possibility of using a dynamic 'where' statement. When searching for this I was redirected several times to solution based on PredicateBuilder class but this requires a Method Syntax instead of Query Syntax. Do I need convert my query to lambda or there is another way to accomplish this?

My additional 'where' (as I already have some 'where' conditions) statement should look similar to:

```
where
( a.field1 = a[0] and b.field1 = b[0] ) ||
( a.field1 = a[1] and b.field2 = b[1] ) ||
( a.field1 = a[2] and b.field2 = b[2] ) ||
....
( a.field1 = a[a.Length] and b.field2 = b[b.Length] )
```